# iOS Auto-layout constraints and frames not working

Tags: ios, view, autolayout, constraints, parent-child

I have a Scroll View nested inside a View Controller which is rested in a Container. The View Controller, which uses a specified class called `ScrollingViewController` looks like this:

```
class ScrollingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! //outlet for the Scroll View

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1) Create the two views used in the swipe container view
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "App", bundle: nil)
        var subOne: SubProfileOneViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("subone") as! SubProfileOneViewController
        var subTwo: SubProfileTwoViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("subtwo") as! SubProfileTwoViewController

        // 2) Add in each view to the container view hierarchy
        //    Add them in opposite order since the view hierarchy is a stack
        self.addChildViewController(subTwo);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(subTwo.view);
        subTwo.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(subOne);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(subOne.view);
        subOne.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        // 3) Set up the frames of the view controllers to align
        //    with each other inside the container view
        var adminFrame :CGRect = subOne.view.frame;
        adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width;
        subTwo.view.frame = adminFrame;

        // 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
        var scrollWidth: CGFloat  = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        var scrollHeight: CGFloat  = 262
        self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Basically what's happening is that two View Controllers that use that class `SubProfileOneViewController` and `SubProfileTwoViewController`, respectively, are being instantiated as `subOne` and `subTwo`. These are then added into the Scroll View as children in order to create an interface where the user can swipe right to access another view (almost like Snapchat). `subOne` and `subTwo` should be side by side and the user should be able to scroll from one to the next and vice versa.

Here's what this all looks like on my storyboard:
[image]

`SubProfileOneViewController` and `SubProfileTwoViewController` each have a view (represented by green and red respectively) and each have the same exact constraints which are: Height = 262, Trailing space to superview = 0, Leading space to superview = 0, Top space to superview = 0

Ideally, when run, there should be two views, one green and one red and the user should be able to swipe between each one. However, here's what actually happens:
[image]

The green and red views don't take up the entire screen width and instead are condensed into a small sliver on the left, and the majority of the View Controllers are white instead of their respective color. I've tried many things and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

(credit for code in `ScollingViewController` goes to lbrendanl on github, linked here: https://github.com/lbrendanl/SwiftSwipeView)

Comment: what constraints you have used for the container views inside scrollview. can you post a sample project?

Comment: I would add a single UIView (contentView) to your `UIScrollView`. Then add your child controller views inside the content view. Add constraints for your child views which pin their top & bottom to the content view. For view one, pin the leading to the content view then pin its trailing to view two leading. Finally pin view two trailing to the content view. To force the widths to be right you need constraints for the width for view one and view two: or add a width constraint for the contentView to be x2 teh screen and add constraints for view one and view two to have equal widths.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *I would recommend using an `Autolayout` solution, which will automatically handle orientation changes, screen sizes, all with much less code and more robust solution than what I develop below*.

With the current approach, using **embedded** `UIViewControllers`, you must wait for these controllers to complete their respective initializations, which are in direct competition with your layout.
*Note that you will need to recalculate positions + sizes upon orientation changes*. Again, while this works, it is **not** a sound design since it calls for a lot of code, logic, and general functionalities you would get for free using `NSLayoutConstraint`.

(*tested, built, linked and ran*):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // 3) Set up the frames of the view controllers to align
    //    with each other inside the container view
    var adminFrame = self.view.frame
    subOne.view.frame = adminFrame
    adminFrame.offset(dx: self.view.frame.width, dy: 0)
    subTwo.view.frame = adminFrame;

    // 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
    let scrollWidth = 2 * self.view.frame.width
    self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, self.view.frame.height)
}
```

Here is the scrolling (*in action*). Notice that I created views of class [ViewLayoutAssistant.swift](https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/003be02e89204cad8fea) which allows you to visualize position + scale very conveniently.

[image]

You also do not need to tell the view its hierarchy has changed. This last bit of code should get you going:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
weak var subOne: SubProfileOneViewController!
weak var subTwo: SubProfileTwoViewController!

    self.addChildViewController(subTwo);
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(subTwo.view);
    self.addChildViewController(subOne);
    self.scrollView!.addSubview(subOne.view);
```

Answer (score 2):

ScrollView with auto layout works differently either you can use only one subview by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` and setting contentSize explicitly. Or you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and let it find out constraint it self. Visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) for more details

As you want both should take full screen then you need to add AutoLayoutConstraints, something like this

1. Pin greenView left to super view
2. Set greenView width to same as scrollViewWidth i.e bounds.size.width (not contetnSizeWidth)
3. Pin redView left to greenView right
4. set redView width value same as scrollViewWidth i.e bounds.size.width (not contetnSize.width)